# Set Navigation bar to active?

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink, navbar

How i can change the navigation bar to active? It doesn't work with a:active! And I tried many ways with jQuery, but without success. Please can someone help me. I have no more ideas.

This is my CSS I used:

```
    #head-balken{
    width:auto;
    height:5px;
    background-color:#00C;
    margin-left:110px;  
}

    #header {

    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #666;
    line-height: 52px;
    height: 52px;
    margin-left:110px;

    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

    .menu {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: 'Gudea', sans-serif;
}


    .menu:hover{

    position:relative;
    height:55px;
    top:-3px;
    background-color: #00C;

    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;

}

    .menu.active{

    position:relative;
    height:55px;
    top:-3px;
    background-color: black;

    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;

}
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/head.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gudea' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script>

</script>

<title>HBH-Interne</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="head-picture">
        <img src="image/hbhlogo.jpg" width="110px" height="57px" />
    </div>    


    <div id="header">
        <ul id="nav"> 
            <a href="home.php?seite=interne"><li class="menu">Interne Funktionen</li></a>
            <a href="home.php?seite=doku"><li class="menu" >Dokumentation</li></a>
            <a href="home.php?seite=desktop "><li class="menu" >Desktop Sitzungen</li></a>
            <a href="home.php?seite=admin"><li class="menu" >Administration</li></a>

            <a href="#"><li class="login" >Login</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="head-balken"></div>        

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "change to active"?

Comment: Fix your ul li HTML. Put a tag inside li

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your CSS, you'll have to add the class "active" to your li.

So:

```
<li class="menu active">Interne Funktionen</li>
```

Comment: but if i do this, this one will everytime highlighted and not only when its active.

Comment: Well, you'll have to tell it when it's active. For example, you could look at the current URL and then toggle the class for the correct item (as JHuangweb suggested).

Answer (score 0):

User jQuery toggleClass()

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Try this out yourself and if you have any questions, post back.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

This is my solution:

```
    var page = document.location.href;

    // Get current URL
    var href = window.location.href;

    // Remove trailing slash
    href = href.substr(-1) == '/' ? href.substr(0, href.length - 1) : href;

    // Get last part of current URL
    page = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
    console.log(page);


    if(page == 'interne'){
      $('#interne').addClass('active');
    }
    else{
      $('#interne').removeClass('active');
    }
```

Comment: Suppose you have 100 menu item, you will write all of them in if else condition?